# Assign multiple variables at once in scala

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
val text = "some text goes here"
val (first, rest) = text.splitAt(4)
println(first + " *" + rest)
```

That works fine.

However, I want to have two cases, defining "first" and "rest" outside, like this:

```
val text = "some text goes here"
var (first, rest) = ("", "")
if (text.contains("z")) {
  (first, rest) = text.splitAt(4)
} else {
  (first, rest) = text.splitAt(7)
}
println(first + " *" + rest)
```

But that gives me an error:

```
scala>      | <console>:2: error: ';' expected but '=' found.
         (first, rest) = text.splitAt(4)
```

Why is it an error to do (first, rest) = text.splitAt(4) but not to do val (first, rest) = text.splitAt(4)? And what can I do?

Edit: Can't re-assign val, changed to var. Same error

Comment: Interesting, when typing in 2.9.1-final REPL `text splitAt 4` second string is printed with redundant quotes `(some," text goes here")`. Is it a known bug?

Comment: Oh, it's not a bug, it's a feature! String is printed with extra quotes when starts or ends with whitespace. I love Scala :)

Answer (score 15):

First of all `val` is immutable, so you can't reassign it. Second, `if`, like all control structures in Scala, can return a value. So, you can do it like this:

```
val text = "some text goes here"
val (first, rest) = if (text.contains("z")) text.splitAt(4) else text.splitAt(7)
println(first + " *" + rest)
```

Comment: Or a little more concisely: `val (first, rest) = text.splitAt(if (text.contains("z")) 4 else 7)`.

Comment: @SerJ - Of course, silly mistake about val. And yes, I could do it with an if, but the point still stands - why did I get the error in the first place?

Comment: @user1229043 see other answers and try to read more about pattern matching and extractors

Comment: @SerJ - Yes, I see the other answer now, it was posted after I made that comment. Thanks :)

Answer (score 15):

The answer by Serj gives a better way of writing this, but for an answer to your question about why your second version doesn't work, you can go to the [Scala specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), which makes a distinction between *variable definitions* and *assignments*.

From "4.2 Variable Declarations and Definitions":

> Variable definitions can alternatively have a pattern (§8.1) as
>   left-hand side. A variable definition `var p = e` where `p` is a
>   pattern other than a simple name or a name followed by a colon and a
>   type is expanded in the same way (§4.1) as a value definition `val p
>   = e`, except that the free names in `p` are introduced as mutable variables, not values.

From "6.15 Assignments":

> The interpretation of an assignment to a simple variable `x = e` depends
>   on the definition of `x`. If `x` denotes a mutable variable, then the
>   assignment changes the current value of `x` to be the result of
>   evaluating the expression `e`.

`(first, rest)` here is a pattern, not a simple variable, so it works in the variable definition but not in the assignment.

Comment: Thanks. So there isn't a way of assigning multiple variables using a pattern other than in a variable definition?

Comment: @user1229043 Pattern matching exists on `match`, on `for` comprehensions, on `val`/`var` declarations and on `catch`. There's no way to do (re-)assignment to multiple variables at the same time.

Answer (score 12):

SerJ de SuDDeN answer is absolutely correct but some more details why the code you mentioned works the way it works.

```
val (a, b) = (1, 2)
```

is called an extractor of a pattern-match-expression. The value on the right side is matched to the extractor of the left side. This can be done everywhere in Scala and can have different faces. For example a pattern match on a List can look something like

```
scala> val head :: tail = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
head: Int = 1
tail: List[Int] = List(2, 3)
```

On the right side the `::`-symbol is a method of class List which prepends elements to it. On the left side the `::`-symbol is an extractor of class `::`, a subclass of List.

Some other places can be for-comprehensions

```
scala> for ((a, b) <- (1 to 3) zip (4 to 6)) println(a+b)
5
7
9
```

or the equivalent notation with higher-order-methods

```
scala> (1 to 3) zip (4 to 6) foreach { case (a, b) => println(a+b) }
5
7
9
```

Comment: Worked for me with little difference: val List(a, b) = (1, 2)