# Assign same value to multiple variables in Scala

Tags: scala

I have 3 variables that have already been initialized, and I want to assign a new value to all three of them. e.g.

```
var a = 1
var b = 2
var c = 3
```

and I want to reassign them to the same value e.g.

```
a = b = c = 4
```

But the above expression is invalid. Is there a right way to do this in Scala?

Comment: Two thoughts: a) Three separate assignment are not too terrible.  b) Scala programmers avoid mutable variables, so this issue probably does not come up too much (and did not get special syntax). Maybe take a step back and see if you cannot replace the variables with `val`s.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418576/assign-multiple-variables-at-once-in-scala

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998724/what-is-the-motivation-for-scala-assignment-evaluating-to-unit-rather-than-the-v

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to slightly shorten the `var` definition code as follows

```
var (a, b, c) = (1, 2, 3)
```

This works because of [extractor objects](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html) in scala. A tuple of 3 is extracted into 3 components it was created with.

But following does **not** work becase the extraction is applied on `val` or `var` definitions.

```
(a, b, c) = (4, 4, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var Seq(a, b, c) = Seq.fill(3)(4)
```

As with Ivan's solution, this only works when declaring vars or vals, not when reassigning. Since the second parameter is computed for each element, it even works well for mutable objects:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

var Seq(a, b, c) = Seq.fill(3)(ListBuffer[Int]())
a += 1  // Only modifies a, not b or c.
```

By contrast, something like `a = b = c = []` will only create one list in most programming languages (e.g. Python, JavaScript, Java). If you don't want to create your object each time (perhaps because it is immutable and creation is expensive), declare it as `val` first to prevent this behavior:

```
val largeObject = ???
var Seq(a, b, c) = Seq.fill(3)(largeObject)
```