# Scala assigning multiple returned values from a function

Tags: scala

Given this Scala function

```
def mv: (Int,Int,Int) = {
  (1,2,3)
}
```

The following works

```
val (i,j,k) = mv
```

But this does not

```
var i = 0
var j = 0
var k = 0
(i,j,k) = mv
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '=' found.
   (i,j,k) = mv
           ^
```

This implies that assigning to multiple variables only works when they are initialized? or maybe I'm writing it incorrectly? Trying to find a way to return several values from a function and assign the values to instance variables in a Class, which means the variables can't be initialized when the function is called because they are declared outside of all methods.

```
class C {
  var i = 0
  var j = 0
  var k = 0
  def mv: (Int,Int,Int) = {
    (1,2,3)
  }
  def changeState: Unit = {
    (i,j,k) = mv
  }
}
```

The above does not work. I could create a case class to hold the return values but would like to make something this work since it seems more clear.

Comment: Please note update following comments on initial proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make it work but it seems wrong minded:

```
class C {
  var i = 0
  var j = 0
  var k = 0
  def mv: (Int,Int,Int) = {
    (1,2,3)
  }
  def changeState: Unit = {
    val (x,y,z) = mv
    i = x
    j = y
    k = z
  }
}

val c = new C
c.i == 0 //true
c.changeState
c.i == 1 //true so this works
```

So it works but is ugly

Comment: This is the best solution, anyway. Scala does not support multiple assignment (ScalaReference section 6.15). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348751/scala-multiple-assignment-to-existing-variable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776651/scala-tuple-deconstruction @user3189923 's answer is misguiding.

Comment: Yeah, too bad but true. Scala implicitly determines what to do and so hides what is really happening sometimes. That's nice usually, it leads to less verbose code, but it also can obscure problems. The multivalued return is really a hidden Tupple3[Int,Int,Int] I think.