# Scala: load Java properties

Tags: java, scala, properties

What would be easy to read and understand, Scala code to load Java properties according to the following Java code:

```
    try {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
        this.host = prop.getProperty("mongo.host");
        this.port = new Integer(prop.getProperty("mongo.port"));
        this.dbName = prop.getProperty("mongo.db");
        this.docsCollName  = prop.getProperty("mongo.coll.docs");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please, give it a try yourself first! Then come back with any questions you may have.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mostly the same (if you're not using any config library):

```
val (host, port, dbName, docsCollName) = 
  try {
    val prop = new Properties()
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"))

    (
      prop.getProperty("mongo.host"),
      new Integer(prop.getProperty("mongo.port")),
      prop.getProperty("mongo.db"),
      prop.getProperty("mongo.coll.docs")
    ) 
    } catch { case e: Exception => 
      e.printStackTrace()
      sys.exit(1)
    }
```

Comment: And what is `val (host, port, dbName, docsCollName)` ? Is it an anonymous tuple or list? Where to read about this construct? (I have not yet seen such constructs in the docs)

Comment: @AntonAshanin it is [destructuring assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2776847/298389) which takes result of try block (in case of success) and then assigns returned values to set of local values. This way you can use only vals and no vars.

Comment: Very cool and a lot of fun too )) For example: `val (x, z) = (123, "xexe".toInt)`. In case exception happens inside assignment block - none of the variables get instantiated. Very predictive programming, indeed - maximum surprise guaranteed! ))

Comment: @AntonAshanin well, you're calling System.exit() if something going wrong, so why do you care about instantiation?

Comment: @om-nom-nom +1 on sys.exit. @AntonAshanin since `try` is an expression in Scala and not a statement, you can replace `new Integer(prop.getProperty("mongo.port"))` by `try { Integer.valueOf(prop.getProperty("mongo.port"))} catch { case e: Exception => defaultIntegerValue }` and it will return `defaultIntegervalue` if the integer parsing fails

Comment: @AntonAshanin please avoid such easy sarcasm because it's out of context here, we're trying to help you. You can do a lot to make your program more "predictive", as you'd like, by using a [Try](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Try) for example, as shown in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5254565).

Answer (score 19):

I will certainly recommend the [typesafe config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config), written by the company behind Scala and used at least by Akka framework.

Features (quoted from wiki):

- implemented in plain Java with no dependencies
- extensive test coverage
- supports files in three formats: Java properties, JSON, and a human-friendly JSON superset
- merges multiple files across all formats
- can load from files, URLs, or classpath
- good support for "nesting" (treat any subtree of the config the same as the whole config)
- users can override the config with Java system properties, java -Dmyapp.foo.bar=10 supports configuring an app, with its framework and libraries, all from a single file such as application.conf
- parses duration and size settings, "512k" or "10 seconds"
- converts types, so if you ask for a boolean and the value is the string "yes", or you ask for a float and the value is an int, it will
  figure it out.
- JSON superset features:
     comments
     includes
     substitutions ("foo" : ${bar}, "foo" : Hello ${who})
     properties-like notation (a.b=c)
     less noisy, more lenient syntax
     substitute environment variables

Example:

```
Config conf = ConfigFactory.load();
int bar1 = conf.getInt("foo.bar");
Config foo = conf.getConfig("foo");
int bar2 = foo.getInt("bar");
```

Comment: It's also in the Scala Distribution from 2.10.0 and forwards

Comment: another reason to use it, as Viktor is saying, any time you fire actors in scala 2.10 you depend on akka-actors and config. [http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html]

Comment: Yes, I agree with your reasoning, but sometimes you need something really simple, and have no time to deviate from the main goal and learn "yet another configuration framework".