# Can I destructure (pattern extract) a Scala list into a reused var?

Tags: scala, destructuring

I have a Scala list. I can destructure the list into some variables thus:

```
var a :: b :: tail = myList
a should be ("A1")
b should be ("B1")
tail should be ('empty)
```

However, I do not seem to be able to reuse the same variables for another destructuring:

```
a :: b :: tail = anotherList
a should be ("A2")
b should be ("B2")
tail should be ('empty)
```

The compiler tells me that it expected a semi-colon but found an equals sign. Why is this? 
Is it impossible to use already-declared variables when destructuring? Am I doing something stupid?

Comment: a :: b :: tail - creates list (object). Like '3' :: '5' :: '3'. It is object - not variable. So you can not reuse variables - there are used to create this list.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2776651/298389

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pattern extraction requires a `case`, `val` or `var` prefix or must occur within a `for` expression. Therefore, re-assigning the variables is not possible.

---

The Scala Language lists these cases in §§4.1 (values), 4.2 (variables), 6.19 (for-comprehensions) and 8.4 (pattern matching expressions)

Comment: This would be a much better answer with a reference to the language specification.

Comment: I guess that's a "No" then. Although to clarify, I CAN reassign the variables, just not using another pattern extraction.